# How to find a .zip file in the current directory using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a .zip file in the current directory, I want to get its file name using Groovy. e.g. if the file is myfile.zip, I want to get the "myfile" part. Can anyone give me a code snip? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
filename=new File("directory").listFiles().find{it.name.endsWith(".zip")}
```

If you don't want the .zip on the end, subtract it:

```
filename=new File("directory").listFiles().find{it.name.endsWith(".zip")}.name - ".zip"
```

(By the way, the first one ends up with a file object--you can do whatever you want with it.  The second ends up with the string that is the name without the .zip)

Comment: This is result on Windows, thank you! filename=.\archive_1.0.0.zip
filename=archive_1.0.0